# MX Linux ISO checksum mismatch

Tags: hashsum, checksum, mx-linux

I went to the MX Linux website and their "Direct Download" linked me to their [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mx-linux/files/) downloads page. I selected the first option - `MX-19.2_September_x64.iso` then checked the download using [this](https://download.cnet.com/MD5-SHA-Checksum-Utility/3000-2092_4-10911445.html) utility.

MX website lists this -

```
Checksums and signatures of Final ISOs

MX-19.2_386.iso
md5sum: 6f5b12f9147bf457286e27196c501390
sha256: 187781c59394d086f347b00afe2f75e38e18a1044624998939c8403b40d4975e
signature

MX-19.2_x64.iso
md5sum: a8f62099a9567e146108c51457183ad3
sha256: 7cf6d7dafe8200e7553f3548121eac077e87f891b5cdb939c0b677b9d7720e4c
signature

MX-19.2_ahs_x64.iso
md5sum: 01435f705690c1bddfe3abf0921d0168
sha256: 20611c53c0015b1f2fc6eee4b6ef43a6738eeada50c66f7e66a5c88dd68fe763
signature

MX-19.2_KDE_x64.iso
md5sum: 065b1b9e1b798e776553778cebf48161
sha256: 0464b9ea35a3254eacc0a62eb64e36ba9a85591767cc6fd858f21a9617aedc66
signature
```

The SHA256 (and MD5) I got after running the utility doesn't match the string given on MX's website. Am I testing it wrong or is the ISO not genuine?

Comment: Can you testit directly on a linux  `md5sum file` ? or try with other checksum tools ? re download them maybe ?

Comment: It looks like he's not running Linux.

Comment: @Archemar I ran the "sha256sum" command on linux and it returned the same string as the utility's I used. Doesn't match the string on MX's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right! Here is what I got for `MX-19.2_September_x64.iso` from the "*Snapshots"* directory:

```
$ md5sum MX-19.2_September_x64.iso
e1c424823243b3b5371953b22bc2307c  MX-19.2_September_x64.iso
$ sha256sum MX-19.2_September_x64.iso
340ed960ac91e6c52f845278a4f2b751af7ce458f8ba126a3076564b5f8b1cef  MX-19.2_September_x64.iso
```

But the checksums on the website are not for `MX-19.2_September_x64.iso`, which is a monthly snapshot of the MX Linux. The checksums on the website are for `MX-19.2_x64.iso` from the "*Final*" directory:

```
$ md5sum MX-19.2_x64.iso
a8f62099a9567e146108c51457183ad3  MX-19.2_x64.iso
$ sha256sum MX-19.2_x64.iso
7cf6d7dafe8200e7553f3548121eac077e87f891b5cdb939c0b677b9d7720e4c  MX-19.2_x64.iso
```